# javascript run .exe client on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exe, execute

I will develop MVC with ASP.NET and I can run exe file on the IE browser client. 
This code

```
MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
MyObject.Run({application path});
```

But I can't call it on the chrome brower. 
 Do you have sample javascript code?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't run arbitrary programs on a person's computer on chrome

Comment: ActiveX is an IE+Win only framework: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX
maybe there are some third-party plugin for chrome, but you cannot rely on them

Comment: ActiveXObject is an IE specific object

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that alot of companys disable activex because of security reasons. And starting a program with javascript code is a bad idea (even if the browser allows it!).

Is the program related to some kind of file type? You might load a file for the program that let the browser start the application. Like downloading pdfs starts acrobat...

Comment: It working similar to single sign on system. When user account sing-in system who see application links . There are web application and window application.